# removing migration and adding another one with similar stats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I have migration called "sign_substrate" which looks like:

```
class CreateJoinTableSignSubstrate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :signs, :substrates do |t|
      # t.index [:sign_id, :substrate_id]
      # t.index [:substrate_id, :sign_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to remove it, and add similar one instead of her (the one listed below):

```
class CreateJoinTableCategorySubstrate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :categories, :substrates do |t|
      # t.index [:category_id, :substrate_id]
      # t.index [:substrate_id, :category_id]
    end
  end
end
```

What I did was, used command `rails d migration CreateJoinTableSignSubstrate` which did nothing I think(or it did), because when I restarted my SQLite Manager, the table was still there, so I used and removed I manually from file system (right click delete on migration in files ).

After creating this migrations, what I did was, I went to models, and modified a few models, manually (I am not sure can I do that) and added a couple of new associations in models. (like has_many etc etc)

Ran `rake db:migrate` after everything.

My questions here are:

1. What are the correct ways of deleting one migration, and also deleting it from database.
2. Is my way of adding new associations to models a  good one, or I did some mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the migration to remove a column or delete a table in same way as you do to generate them. From [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration):

```
rails generate migration RemovePartNumberFromProducts part_number:string
```

generates

```
class RemovePartNumberFromProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :products, :part_number, :string
  end
end
```

To destroy a model:

```
rails destroy model ModelName
```

For your associations doubt, **you specify** the associations in your models, but the associations are possible only by *referencing foreign ids* or *join tables* etc. For them, you will **have** to generate the suitable migrations anyway; so associations are the team work of migrations + models. Just specifying the associations in models won't actually associate them unless their referencing keys are present.

Comment: Yes but i dont want to destroy a model, i just want to edit it.

Comment: @Michael If you you want to remove a migration, use `rake db:rollback` if it's the last migration itself; else apply inverse migration with the `RemoveXXXfromYYY` as I mentioned above.

Comment: aaaahhhaaaaaaaaa, so if i understood correctly, first i remove specific migration (rails d migration CreateJoinTableSignSubstrate (in my case)) and then i create a new migration i want. I also delete models associated with that migration i deleted, and create a new models with associations i want. 
all this i do from terminal, not manually.
am i missing something or ?

Comment: Partially, yes. If migration you wish to remove is old, `destroy` them. You don't need to delete your models, you can just edit them to suit your needs(and associations) and then generate suitable migrations.

Comment: yeah, but editing models i do from editor or do i have to generate again?

Comment: you can just use the editor, no need to generate the model again; Because, if you generate the model, it will generate the migration for that again and that may conflict with your partial removal of `destroy`ed migration

Comment: Question..After adding all associations and adding new migrations with join & adding some test examples in my SQLite db, i cant see relation between 2 models. Like i have 2 models (categories and substrate). 
Category (has_many :substrates
    has_and_belongs_to_many :substrates) and Substrate(has_and_belongs_to_many :categories)
After making relations there is nothing in the view. any suggestions? :) 
PS:sorry if its offtopic a bit.

Comment: Why `has_many :substrates` when you already have HABTM there? I presume you created migration for `CategorySubstrate` correctly; are records being saved?

Comment: Yeah, i removed it ( it was there since i was testing all possible ways ). Well yeah, everything is created, and records are being saved. Im thinking that error might be in join or so, since i dont see anything on the view :/

Comment: @Michael I'm afraid it is a separate question on it's own. Need more code flow to look how you are proceeding and schema etc. You may pose a new question about that :)

Answer (score 0):

The step you missed is first rolling back the migration. You should use `rake db:rollback` to undo the last migration before you remove it and add the new one.